# How can I print a data that comes as index.html in an iframe? With Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

ts side;

```
  webURL: SafeHtml = "";
  @Input() set selectedJob(job: any) {
    this.mediaService.matchedIframe(this.jobId).subscribe((website: any) => {


      this.webURL = this.sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(website.htmlContent)

    })

    this.currentJob = job;

  }
```

html side;

```
<iframe [src]="webURL"></iframe>
```

The data coming to my WebURL address is as follows.

[image: like this]

Comment: What do you mean by print? To the console? To an actual printer? display it on the screen?

Comment: to my web screen, When I try to print the data it gives the following error ;"value used in a resource URL context"

Comment: https://filipmolcik.com/error-unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context/ would this help?

Comment: yes, when i do this my page opens again inside my page